# Can't install/update plugin wordpress in macos local

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using default apache of macos. My wp site can't install new or update plugins. **But this is working normal in live site**. These are list error I can see while I'm trying to install a new plugin:

> Error notice: **Installation failed: Internal Server Error**
>
> Status on button install now: **Update Failed!**
>
> In console debug I see: **.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)**

I tried to search and do in some ways, ex: change chown, permission to 777, added define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'), change memory_limit...
But still don't working.

So I went throught and I saw when I comment in the line `@set_time_limit( 300 );` at line 450 in file `.../wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php` I see it's working. But I don't understand why this happen?

```
public function install_package( $args = array() ) {
    global $wp_filesystem, $wp_theme_directories;

    $defaults = array(
        'source' => '', // Please always pass this
        'destination' => '', // and this
        'clear_destination' => false,
        'clear_working' => false,
        'abort_if_destination_exists' => true,
        'hook_extra' => array()
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    // These were previously extract()'d.
    $source = $args['source'];
    $destination = $args['destination'];
    $clear_destination = $args['clear_destination'];

    //@set_time_limit( 300 ); **If I comment at here it's working**

    if ( empty( $source ) || empty( $destination ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'bad_request', $this->strings['bad_request'] );
    }
    $this->skin->feedback( 'installing_package' );
....
}
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To protect web servers from abuse, there is a **time limit set for how long a PHP script can run**. For example, if your server receives 100 requests that have no time limit, they may run forever and occupy the whole RAM.

The problem with your local machine is the execution time for plugin installation bigger than 300 seconds (5 minutes). It may cause by the internet speed or Apache.

There are 3 options to fix it:

**Option 1:**

Comment out `@set_time_limit( 300 );` as you do, but don't update the file on production.

**Option 2:**

Add this line to `wp-config.php`:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

It's the same like option 1 so don't update the file on production.

**Option 3:**

Use a better local development env (recommended), [VCCW](http://vccw.cc/) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jared Chu, I just tried on "option 2" but it don't work for me. About option 3 maybe it can help me but I don't want to try it now, maybe later. And now I can think my problem is can't execute any code after @set_time_limit( 300 ). /T

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` may work, but it doesn't matter if you modify `class-wp-upgrader.php` or `wp-config.php`

Comment: I don't know why, but I fixed my problem by upgrade php from 5.6 to PHP 7. So I put here, if anyone have same problem can try it.

Comment: congrats, I think it works because PHP7 has great performance